# Facial recognition with neural net

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, facial-identification

For the facial recognition example in deep learning, the features (nose, eyes, lips etc.) are analyzed in the first hidden layer. If we wanted to analyzed more features such as dimples, skin type, skin color, wrinkles and etc. would we have add more nodes to the first hidden layer or would we add more hidden layers to the network? If either solution works, which solution is the better in terms of performance and reduction in complexity?

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer: it depends on many different factors (mainly on your dataset).

But usually for the same amount of neurons it is better to use more hidden layers with small number of neurons instead of one layer with large number of neurons.

If you want more details, please check a great article by Jeff Heaton:

https://www.heatonresearch.com/2017/06/01/hidden-layers.html

From that article:

> Num Hidden Layers:
>
> **none:** Only capable of representing linear separable functions or decisions.
>
> **1:** Can approximate any function that contains a continuous mapping from one finite space to another.
>
> **2:** Can represent an arbitrary decision boundary to arbitrary accuracy with rational activation functions and can approximate any smooth mapping to any accuracy.
>
> **>2:** Additional layers can learn complex representations (sort of automatic feature engineering) for layer layers.

and

> There are many rule-of-thumb methods for determining an acceptable
> number of neurons to use in the hidden layers, such as the following:
>
> - The number of hidden neurons should be between the size of the input layer and the size of the output layer.
> - The number of hidden neurons should be 2/3 the size of the input layer, plus the size of the output layer.
> - The number of hidden neurons should be less than twice the size of the input layer.